# Firedac: How to set up TFDBatchMove with data set reader / writer?

Tags: c++, firedac, c++builder-xe8

I am attempting to set up a `TFDBatchMove` object called `FDBatchMove` with a reader and writer dataset. According to [this documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove)

> An application should assign the required reader and writer to the properties, and then call the Execute method.

According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.15/libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.DataSet.TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader) for `TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader` one should

> Use TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader to define the source dataset from which to load information using TFDBatchMove. 
>   
> Set the DataSet property to select the dataset.
>  Choose the TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader as the Reader property of the TFDBatchMove.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.15/libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.DataSet.TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter) for `TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter` contains the same steps.

Therefore, I have created a `TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader` and a `TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter` object, and set their dataset values like so:

```
TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader * Reader = new TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader( this );
Reader->DataSet = MyDataSet1;

TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader * Writer = new TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader( this );
Writer->DataSet = MyDataSet2;
```

However, I run into an issue when I attempt to set the reader and writer property of my `TFDBatchMove` object (i.e. the third step in the documentation).

The code...

```
FDBatchMove->Reader = Reader;
FDBatchMove->Writer = Writer;
```

...gives me the following errors:

```
E2034 Cannot convert 'TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader *' to '_di_IFDBatchMoveReader'

E2034 Cannot convert 'TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter *' to '_di_IFDBatchMoveWriter'
```

I tried explicitly creating a new `_di_IFDBatchMoveReader` object, however that object does not give me access to the Dataset property.  How am I supposed to set up my `TFDBatchMove` object with a dataset reader and dataset writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this delphi [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FireDAC.TFDBatchMove_Sample) I have figured out the solution.  In order to apply the `TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader` and `TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter` objects to a `TFDBatchMove` object, you place the `TFDBatchMove` object in their constructors as the owner parameter.  So in my case, it would look like this:

```
TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader * Reader = new TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader( FDBatchMove );
TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader * Writer = new TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader( FDBatchMove );
```